# instantiate oc create -f abc.yaml from a microservice already running in Openshift

Tags: java, microservices, openshift

I am working on a use case and got stuck here, wanted to run oc create -f abc.yaml , from a microservice which is already running on Openshift, So , when we run oc create -f abc.yaml , few workloads need to be created on same Openshift cluster.

Any idea how to do it. Please

Comment: some existing microservice wont be created(does not change on cluster) when you run `oc create`

Comment: sorry, didnt get you. xyz microservice is already as Pod in Openshift, and wanted to run oc create -f abc.yaml, inside the pod programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Does "oc replace ..." do what you want instead?

Comment: No, i am trying to create few workloads each time using oc create -f abc.yaml